# HTML page not compatible with all screen sizes

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<title>website page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="50%" height="50%">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (website page.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1681" height="1051" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_01.gif" width="302" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/website-page_02.gif" width="999" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_03.gif" width="379" height="65" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="65" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/website-page_04.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_05.gif" width="299" height="606" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="7" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_06.gif" width="1050" height="606" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_07.gif" width="328" height="606" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/website-page_08.gif" width="3" height="984" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="605" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_09.gif" width="639" height="379" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_10.gif" width="18" height="379" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_11.gif" width="342" height="379" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_12.gif" width="22" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/website-page_13.gif" width="656" height="379" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/website-page_14.gif" width="21" height="378" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/website-page_15.gif" width="1" height="378" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="378" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="299" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="340" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="18" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="342" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="21" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="277" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="51" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="328" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

after I finished designing the page using PS and export it as html file, it is ok with 15 inch screen but very big with 13 inch screen.
how can I make it compatible with all screens , with out scrolling .

Solution Update:
I resized the psd file and make it smaller 780*800 , then export it as image/HTML and it is work fine now with all browsers.

Comment: The largest width is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Update: I resized the psd file and make it smaller 780*800 , then export it as image/HTML and it is work fine now with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You 15 inch display must have higher resolution than the 13 inch display. So its looking bigger. Your webpage should look same on any display having same resolution. You should check your resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Make  `<img src="images/website-page_02.gif" width="999" height="65" alt=""></td>` 's width smaller.